# Duplicate row and everything related to that ID in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a software for managing the Rally company of my boss, where he can manage all the volunteers, their affectations, and many other things.
But the volunteers and these others things vary depending on the event, so they all have a column representing the event that they are linked/related to.

My boss requested that I add a "duplicate" button, that would duplicate an event (from my events table) and also duplicate all the volunteers, and values from any other table that is linked to that event, so the new duplications are linked to the new event.

The reason for this, is that he is constantly organizing rallies, and often it happens that the data from a Rally (event) to another is almost the same, so instead of adding it all manually, he'd rather make an entire duplication of the event and all the data related to it, then manually add and remove the errors in it.

I would like to know, is there any way in MySQL that I could duplicate an event, and everything that is linked to it's ID, even though they are in different tables, and make the duplications have the ID of the new event?

Sadly I don't have very much time, but until I get an answer I can work on other tasks my boss gave me.

Thank you so much to anybody who helps me or gives me any hint!!

EDIT:
Here's the schema of my Database (I know it's kinda dirty and there's issues with it, my boss gave me indications on how to create the database since he used to work in the domain before, but he didn't tell me how to make the links and he wants to make them himself)
And I apologize for the French language and the weird names..
Basically I wish to duplicate an entry in the "event" table, all the "affect" and "lieu" entries that are linked to it, and all the "tache" entries related the the duplicated "lieu" entries.
[image: Database scheme (db_rallye)]

EDIT 2:
Thank you MrMadsen for the Query!
I had to fix it a bit, but here's what it looks like after.

```
SET @NEWEVEN = (SELECT MAX(NO_EVE) from db_rallye.event)+1;

INSERT INTO db_rallye.event
SELECT @NEWEVEN, 
       NM_EVE, 
       AN_EVE, 
       DT_EVE, 
       NM_REG_EVE
FROM event
WHERE NO_EVE = event_to_duplicate;

SET @NO_AFFECT_LIEU = (SELECT MAX(NO_AFF) from db_rallye.affect);
INSERT INTO db_rallye.affect
SELECT @NO_AFFECT_LIEU:=@NO_AFFECT_LIEU+1, 
       CO_AFF, 
       DT_AVI_AFF, 
       DS_STA_AFF, 
       CO_STA_AFF, 
       NO_BRA_EVN, 
       NO_PERS, 
       @NEWEVEN, 
       NO_EQU, 
       NO_LIE, 
       NO_PERS_RES, 
       IN_LUN, 
       IN_BAN,
       DS_HEB,
       IN_HEB_JEU, 
       IN_HEB_VEN, 
       IN_HEB_SAM, 
       NO_BOR, 
       NO_TUL_CAH, 
       NB_SPEC
FROM affect
WHERE NO_EVEN = event_to_duplicate;

INSERT INTO db_rallye.lieu
SELECT NO_LIE, 
       @NEWEVEN, 
       CO_LAT, 
       CO_LON, 
       FI_IMA, 
       FI_CRO, 
       FI_TUL, 
       DS_LIE, 
       DS_COU, 
       DS_LON, 
       NB_BLK,
       VL_KM, 
       IN_FUS,
       VL_DIS_FUS, 
       NO_LIE_FUS_SUI
FROM lieu
WHERE NO_EVEN = event_to_duplicate;

SET @NO_AFFECT_TACHE = (SELECT MAX(NO_TAC) from db_rallye.tache);
INSERT INTO db_rallye.tache
SELECT @NO_AFFECT_TACHE:=@NO_AFFECT_TACHE+1, 
       NO_LIE, 
       @NEWEVEN, 
       NO_AFF, 
       DS_REP, 
       DS_TAC
FROM tache
WHERE NO_LIE IN 
    (SELECT NO_LIE FROM lieu WHERE NO_EVEN = event_to_duplicate);
```

Comment: you don't need to duplicate linked rows, just duplicating the event seems sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a lot of the events contain similar information than I would create a template (or templates and the ability to create/modify templates) containing all of the information that you would duplicate.

Then when a new event is created he can just choose a starting template and then only add whatever data is unique to that event. In my opinion this would be much better than constantly duplicating the data.

As far as how to duplicate a row and all the associated rows, this is completely dependent on your database schema and how the tables relate to one another. If you post the relevant part of that we can help you more.

#### Edit

Here are the queries I came up with, test them in a dev database first but I think they will work. Let me know. Good luck!

```
INSERT INTO `event`
SELECT NULL NO_EVE, 
       NM_EVE, 
       AN_EVE, 
       DT_EVE, 
       NM_REG_EVE
FROM `email_log`
WHERE id NO_EVE = id_of_event_to_duplicate

INSERT INTO `affect`
SELECT NULL NO_AFF, 
       CO_AFF, 
       DT_AVI_AFF, 
       DS_STA_AFF, 
       CO_STA_AFF, 
       NO_BRA_EVN, 
       NO_PERS, 
       NO_EVEN, 
       NO_EQU, 
       NO_LIE, 
       NO_PERS_RES, 
       IN_LUN, 
       IN_BAN, 
       DS_HEB_JEU, 
       IN_HEB_VEN, 
       IN_HEB_SAM, 
       NO_BOR, 
       NO_TUL_CAH, 
       NB_SPEC
FROM `affect`
WHERE NO_EVE = id_of_event_to_duplicate

INSERT INTO `lieu`
SELECT NULL NO_LIE, 
       NO_EVEN, 
       CO_LAT, 
       CO_LON, 
       FI_IMA, 
       FI_CRO, 
       FI_TUL, 
       DS_LIE, 
       DS_COU, 
       DS_LON, 
       DB_BLK,
       VL_KM, 
       IN_FUS,
       VL_DIS_FUS, 
       NO_LIE_FUS_SUI
FROM `lieu`
WHERE NO_EVEN = id_of_event_to_duplicate

INSERT INTO `tache` 
SELECT NULL NO_TAC, 
       NO_LIE, 
       NO_EVEN, 
       NO_AFF, 
       DS_REP, 
       DS_TAC
FROM `tache`
WHERE NO_LIE IN 
    (SELECT NO_LIE FROM `lieu` WHERE NO_EVEN = id_of_event_to_duplicate)
```

Comment: Thank you! What's complicated and I wrongly explained is that there's events at multiple different locations, and those that resemble previous events actually resemble events at that same location, not another. this is why I can't use templates, but thanks for the suggestion!! And I added more information now.

Comment: That schema is really helpful. I'm working out the queries now. I'll edit my answer when I'm done.

Comment: @Benjamin Taillon I added some queries that should work for you. Let me know.